# Variable Names Between Called Batch Files

Tags: windows, environment-variables, batch-file

Let's say I have two batch files, `foo.bat` and `bar.bat`, that are located like so:

```
root\foo.bat
root\grub\bar.bat
```

Let's also say that both files contain a line that sets a variable, like so:

```
set PWD=%cd%
```

Now, if `foo.bat` calls `.\grub\bar.bat`, will `bar.bat` override the `PWD` variable set in `foo.bat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran an experiment.  Changing the environment variable in `bar.bat` causes it to change in `foo.bat`.  I suppose this was to be expected because environment variables set using the `set` command (not `setx`) are scoped to the command session.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 1):

scope is global/ variable is shared as you say..so to echo you, yes.

also, if you use setx it will work for the next cmd session and future ones because it's in the registry., but set and setx aren't  to  be compared in discussion of scope. environment variables are generally global. But you can use setlocal in a batch file at the start and the variables set there remain local

```
C:\DOCUME~1\bob>type n.bat <ENTER>
setlocal
set a=99

C:\DOCUME~1\bob>echo %a% <ENTER>
%a%

C:\DOCUME~1\bob>n <ENTER>

C:\DOCUME~1\bob>setlocal

C:\DOCUME~1\bob>set a=99

C:\DOCUME~1\bob>echo %a% <ENTER>
%a%

C:\DOCUME~1\bob>
```